# Método/Algoritimo para buscar uma data ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, algoritmo, expressões-lambda

Estou com o seguinte problema: Estou tentando buscar uma data. só que não consigo bolar um algoritmo para isso.
Tenho uma classe chamada `RequisicaoDeVeiculo`, essa classe tem o atributo `DataEHoraDoServico`, e tenho outra classe que `MovimentacaoDeVeiculo`, que tem o o atributo `DataEHoraDaChegada`, e a classe `veiculo`.
A classe `RequisicaoDeVeiculo` tem as classes `MovimentacaoDeVeiculo` e `veiculo`. Suponhamos que um usuário fez uma `RequisicaoDeVeiculo`, e saiu para uma missão em um `Veículo` **x** no dia `01/08/2018` ou seja, `DataEHoraDoServico`= `01/08/2018`, esse veículo retornou no dia `05/08/2018`, `DataEHoraDaChegada`= `05/08/2018`. suponhamos que chegou uma multa para esse veículo **X**, e a data da multa é dia `03/08/2018`. então eu quero olhar no meu sistema, quem estava nessa data, com esse veículo. então tenho um formulário no meu sistema com uma **data**, e um DropDow, para escolher um **veículo**. então eu digitei no meu formulario os seguinte dados: `data=03/08/2018` e `Veículo=X`, então tenho uma action que recebe a `data` e `IdDoVeiculo`, e a função assim =>

`var BuscarSolicitacaoPorDataEIdDoVeiculo = db.Meucontexto.Where(x => x.DataEHoraDoServico >= data && x.MovimentacaoDeVeiculo.DataEHoraDaChegada <= data && x.IdVeiculo = IdVeiculo);`
Esse método não da certo pq acontece que ele só buscar solicitações que sejam MAIOR OU IGUAL a **data**, sendo assim, ele busca somente solicitações que tenham sido feito no dia `03/08/2018` ou maior. porém a `DataEHoraDoServico`é igual a  `01/08/2018`. alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você inverteu algo ,

```
db.Meucontexto.Where(x =>
       x.IdVeiculo == IdVeiculo
            &&  
     (dataMulta <= x.DataEHoraChegada && dataMulta >= x.DataEHoraServico)
).ToList();
```

Comment: Cara, valeu, muito obrigado, realmente funcionou. tem momentos que o cérebro trava, e por mais que vc se esforce, não consegue achar uma solução. eu travei nesse simples algoritmo.